# SSIS generate Programmatically: Project connection manager don't appear in the project connection list

Tags: c#, ssis

I create Package from c#,and this code use to work with SQL server 2016 but now with Sql server 2014 its giving me issues :
I am adding the package to the project this way :

```
        proj.PackageItems.Remove("HSTG_" + hstg_table.tablename + ".dtsx");
        proj.PackageItems.Add(p, "HSTG_" + hstg_table.tablename + ".dtsx");
```

In the list of connection of the project i can see 3 Connection manager,
but in the the package i see 0 connection and then of course when i try to access one of them this way p.Connections["META"] it throw me error saying the connection cannot be found.
[image: local_variable]
[local_variable2](https://s15.postimg.org/43gk66f23/project_issue_2jpg.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code for `Cast` command, i.e. what is inside `ForEach` clause? Seems your cast is not working.

Comment: Hi the cast is here just to print out the list of connection however nothing show up on the Console.
 p.Connections.Cast<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager>().ToList<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager>().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("after Connection is:" + x.Name));
           
            // Create a dummy place holder then attah the Eventhandler to it
            ComponentGenerationSSIS2014.createSqlTask(p.Executables, "Dummy placeholder " + p.Name, "Select 1", null, p.Connections["META"], null, SqlStatementSourceType.DirectInput);

Comment: Hm, its strange, I checked and have similar code working with SSIS 2014, package.Connections have Project CMs with reference to Project, added when you add the package to the project. Perhaps, you are keeping references to SSIS 2016 dlls like runtime.wrapper etc. Try to check it, unlink and add correct references again.

Comment: Thanks, i check the reference and they are all SQL2014,i am working in an corporate office and i can't run Visual studio with Admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading an existing ispac,I create one programmatically and it does work. But i still don't understand why it doesn't work in the previous way.

```
 /* Previous way of doing it which work for me on a previous project but not 
working anymore
*/
Project proj = Project.OpenProject(fixed_settings.Default.PROJECT_ISPAC);

// New way by creating the project on the fly
            //Test creation project
            Project proj = Project.CreateProject();
            ConnectionManagerItem connectionManagerItem_meta =   proj.ConnectionManagerItems.Add("OLEDB", "META.conmgr");
            connectionManagerItem_meta.ConnectionManager.Name = "META";
            connectionManagerItem_meta.ConnectionManager.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + fixed_settings.Default.server_meta + ";Initial Catalog=" + fixed_settings.Default.server_meta + ";Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

            ConnectionManagerItem connectionManagerItem_stg = proj.ConnectionManagerItems.Add("OLEDB", "STG.conmgr");
            connectionManagerItem_stg.ConnectionManager.Name = "STG";
            connectionManagerItem_stg.ConnectionManager.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + fixed_settings.Default.server_stg + "; Initial Catalog = " + fixed_settings.Default.database_stg + "; Provider = SQLNCLI11.1; Integrated Security = SSPI; Auto Translate = False;";

            ConnectionManagerItem connectionManagerItem_hstg = proj.ConnectionManagerItems.Add("OLEDB", "HSTG.conmgr");
            connectionManagerItem_hstg.ConnectionManager.Name = "HSTG";
            connectionManagerItem_hstg.ConnectionManager.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + fixed_settings.Default.server_hstg + ";Initial Catalog=" + fixed_settings.Default.database_hstg + ";Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";
```